# Acr_values in azure ad b2c custom policies

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am creating a custom policy in Azure AD B2C. I want to pass some acr_values at the time of authorization to the identityserver. In the regular openid protocol, we can directly pass acr_values as a query parameter in the authorization url but cannot find any similar way of doing that in Azure AD B2C.

Is there any way of doing that configuration in azure ad b2c custom policies ?

Comment: I'm from the engineering team at Microsoft. The answer is yes, but I need to research the how. I'll come back to you with details.

Comment: Any updates on this topic?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can do this using input claims.
In your technical profile add:

```
<InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="acr_values" DefaultValue="somevalue" />
</InputClaims>
```

You will also need to add the ClaimType, e.g.:

```
<ClaimType Id="acr_values">
    <DisplayName>acr_values</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <UserHelpText>Special parameter passed for authentication context</UserHelpText>
</ClaimType>
```